How do i access the results from this API?
I am building a React plus Typescript App and have issues with my code returning the results on the console. I am using the Axios Library to send HTTP Requests, but it is not returning the results.
This is the API Service in the .ts file
import axios from "axios";
const API_KEY = "moby_et03AIZt6I7sbSadzas3SY3YPlY"
// Create an Axios Instance for creating a custom configuration\
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://api.mobygames.com/v1",
    params: {
        key: API_KEY //MY API KEY....

    }
})

And this is the Game Grid, I wanted to use to fetch the games....
import apiClient from "../services/api-client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface Game {
  description: string;
  title: string;
  id: number;
}

interface FetchGameResponse {
  gameID: number;
  games: Game[];
}

const GameGrid = () => {
  // Using a UseState Variable for storing the items in an array
  const [games, setGames] = useState<Game[]>([]);

  //  A State Variable for Setting the Error Messages
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  // Use the UseEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    apiClient
      .get<FetchGameResponse>("/games")
      .then((response) => console.log(response.data.games))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message));
  });

  return (
    <ul>
      {games.map(game=> <li key={game.id}>{game.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
};

export default GameGrid;

What I expected was that I expected results on the console and it is showing me an error i didn't understand

Show us the error so you can understand.

"but it is not returning the results" - Then what is it doing?  If you specifically mean that the AJAX operation is failing in some way, how is it failing?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  If the server-side code is failing in some way then the code shown wouldn't really have anything to do with that.  Please clarify the problem you are observing.

The thing is it is supposed to be returning a list of game titles and specified that, the API is working but i seem to get this error
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mobygames.com/v1/games?key=moby_et03AIZt6I7sbSadzas3SY3YPlY' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
api.mobygames.com/v1/games?key=moby_et03AIZt6I7sbSadzas3SY3YPlY:1
This is the error showing on the console

Does this answer your question? No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API

@IagoCech: There are a great many other duplicates as well.  The error means that the server does not permit cross-origin requests, and the browser is enforcing that.  If you control the server then you can enable these requests, otherwise you can ask whoever controls it how to use it in this scenario.  Alternatively, you can proxy requests through a server you do control.  Another option might be to use (or write) a browser extension which doesn't enforce this policy in this situation.  Or perhaps not make this a web app at all but a desktop app.

@David Thanks  but i'm not in control of the API Server and I'm using Vite as the development environment

@IagoCech: I'm not familiar with Vite specifically, but this looks helpful.  Regardless of the server technology being used, from the browser's perspective the requests just need to go to a server which either allows cross-origin requests or is of the same origin as the page (e.g. your server).  It looks like Vite has functionality to directly proxy requests to a 3rd party API endpoint with just configuration.
